# Using C++ library that comes as .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

I'm trying to use this library: https://github.com/micknoise/Maximilian to do some DSP and am pretty new to C++ compilation which is leading me to some issues,

I'm using Visual Studio 15 and have successfully included a number of statically linked libraries that come in .lib and .a form but am confused on how to link the aforementioned code into my project since it does not come in a compiled form. Simply putting the unzipped project folder (which contains maximilian.h and then a /lib directory with the rest of the .c and .h files) into my include paths leads to linker errors. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Did you add the ".c" files to your project?

Comment: Did you read their instructions at the frontpage? There's already a VisualStudio subfolder containing a (VS2010) project. You should just build that stuff as a separate  project in your solution to get the `.lib` file.

Comment: I did compile that project but I couldn't find anywhere on successful compilation that contained a .lib file. You mention "build as a separate project in your solution" - I'm not too sure what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help above, I was able to get the .lib file by opening the visual studio project and changing the export from .exe to .lib. I then included that in my project and things worked great.